# Why Clojure evaluates forms during AOT compilation?

Tags: clojure, compilation

I've set up small project:

*project.clj*:

```
(defproject testing-compilation "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.8.0"]]

  ;; this is important!
  :aot :all)
```

*src/core.clj*

```
(ns testing-compilation.core)

(def x (do
         (println "Print during compilation?")
         1))
```

Then when I do `lein compile` in project directory I'm seeing output from a print:

```
$ lein compile
Compiling testing-compilation.core
Print during compilation?
```

My question is: why clojure evaluates top level forms during AOT compilation? Shouldn't they be evaluated at program startup?

For reference, [Common Lisp](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_bc.htm) doesn't evaluate forms by default and [provides ability to tune this behaviour](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_eval_w.htm#eval-when). Anything similar in Clojure? If nothing, does Clojure documentation explicitly state such behaviour?

UPD: Forms are evaluated at startup as well.

After specifying a main namespace and writing main function that prints `Hello, world!`, I did this:

```
$ lein uberjar
Compiling testing-compilation.core
Print during compilation?
Created testing-compilation-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Created testing-compilation-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar

$ java -jar target/testing-compilation-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar
Print during compilation?
Hello world!
```

Answer (score 9):

The first part of the AOT process is to find the file containing the main namespace and load it by [evaluating](http://clojure.org/reference/evaluation) every expression from top to bottom.

Some of these expressions will be `require` expressions that will have the effect of loading other namespaces, which recursively load yet more namespaces.

Other will be `defn` expressions that will have the effect of firing up the compiler and producing class files. One class file is produced [for each function](http://clojure.org/reference/compilation#_compiling).

Other expressions may do some calculation and then do things that produce class files, so it's important to give them a chance to run. Here's a made up example:

```
user> (let [precomputed-value (reduce + (range 5))]
        (defn funfunfun [x]
          (+ x precomputed-value)))
#'user/funfunfun
user> (funfunfun 4)
14
```

It is possible to design a lisp that would not evaluate top level forms at start or, as you mention, make it optional. In the case of Clojure it was decided to keep a single evaluation strategy across both AOT and "non AOT" loading so programs always run the same regardless of how they are compiled. These are personal design choices made by others so I can't speak to their motivations here.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Few followups: you mentioned first part of AOT compilation: can you point me to the documentation about stages of AOT compilation (cannot find it)? Also I believe this is not strictly correct, as I can AOT compile without specifying main namespace. Regarding example: it would also work if forms were evaluated only at program startup.

Comment: When you don't specify a main namespace, do you specify :aot-all to load every file? Otherwise it doesn't actually compile anything. Which I don't consider the best user interface :-/ the two links I added together form the most coherent part of the official docs. I'll have to put some time into finding a more concise explanation

Comment: Ah, yeah, `:aot :all` was present.